# how to make formatted excel columns autofit with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview, export-to-excel

I am exporting gridview to excel and this is my code-

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1250\">\n");


        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'\n" +
        "xmlns:x='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel'\n" +

        "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>\n" +
        "<head>\n");
```

Here , i am unable to make columns autofit .
I am confused and searched on google and tried with many solutions but problem remains. 
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `OpenXML` does not support a AutoFit property, its handled internally within Excel by calculating the width of the longest field and storing that width with the column.

You could also look at a more robust library that will do all the heavy lifting in the calculating the widths for you ([`EPPlus`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) and [`EPPlus.Core`](https://github.com/VahidN/EPPlus.Core) springs to mind using the `Worksheet.Column(colIndex).AutoFitColumn()` syntax.